# Why is hydrodynamics a diffeomorphism invariant theory?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, relativity, diffeomorphism-invariance

The fact that general relativity is a diffeomorphism invariant theory means that there is no preferred co-ordinate system in GR. How is it possible to understand this in the context of relativistic hydrodynamics?

Also, while talking about diffeomorphisms generated by a vector field. Which are the vector fields, in the hydrodynamic sense, that generate these diffeomorphisms?

I know that this arbitrary diffeomorphism invariance leads to the stress-energy Tensor conservation equation, but am not able to make complete sense of *what* diffeomorphism invariance actually means.

Comment: The diffeomorphism corresponds to Lagrangian particle mappings, which are volume preserving, expressing conservation of mass. We also have a particle relabeling symmetry in fluid mechanics which expresses vorticity conservation. The vector field here is simply the velocity of the fluid.